# Removing "user accounts" from system settings

Tags: 12.04, unity, system-settings, .desktop

I don't need user account management on my system settings for security reasons. Is it possible to remove user management from settings? Although i don't want it for all user accounts.

---

As given above the dpkg-statoveride is working fine and it's hided the user accounts. But how to show it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove this item in the system settings overview:

[image: user accounts]

Edit the file `/usr/share/applications/gnome-user-accounts-panel.desktop`.

Change the line:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

to:

```
OnlyShowIn=GNOME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the complete account management, but you can hide the icon in the System Settings if that is what you want. Enter the following command in a terminal:
`sudo dpkg-statoverride --update --add root root 640 /usr/share/applications/gnome-user-accounts-panel.desktop`.

Comment: How to show it again in the system settings?